# Designing interface/base classes: How to access list of base class without casting?

Tags: c#, .net

I just wrote this modified code to test some new dotnet features:

```
using System.Text;

namespace Lib1;

public class WriteOnlySqlFile : BaseFile, IWriteOnlySqlFile
{
    public string SaveText()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, save text sql file", FilePath, FileText);
        return "";
    }
}

public class ReadOnlySqlFile : BaseFile, IReadOnlySqlFile
{
    public string LoadText()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}, readonly sql file loading text here!", FilePath, FileText);
        return "";
    }
}

public interface IReadOnlySqlFile
{
    public string LoadText();
}

public interface IWriteOnlySqlFile
{
    public string SaveText();
}

public abstract class BaseFile
{
    public string FilePath { get; init; } = string.Empty;
    public string FileText { get; init; } = string.Empty;
}

public static class SqlFileManager
{
    public static string GetTextFromFiles(List<IReadOnlySqlFile> readOnlySqlFiles)
    {
        StringBuilder objStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var objFile in readOnlySqlFiles)
        {
            objStrBuilder.Append(objFile.LoadText());
        }

        return objStrBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public static void SaveTextIntoFiles(List<IWriteOnlySqlFile> writeOnlySqlFiles)
    {
        foreach (var objFile in writeOnlySqlFiles)
        {
            objFile.SaveText();
        }
    }
}
```

Question is: Can I make `SqlFileManager` non-static and have an instance variable of `BaseFile`s, and iterate over that variable, but without the commented line:

```
{
    public SqlFileManager(List<BaseFile> files)
    {
        LstSqlFiles = files;
    }

    private List<BaseFile> LstSqlFiles { get; }

    public string GetTextFromFiles()
    {
        StringBuilder objStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var objFile in LstSqlFiles)
        {
            //Any SOLID way to access this method but not do the cast? Obviously same cast
            //will have to be in the SaveTextIntoFiles method 
            var sqlFile = objFile as ReadOnlySqlFile;
            objStrBuilder.Append(sqlFile?.LoadText());
        }

        return objStrBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: And what if there is a `WriteOnlySqlFile` in `LstSqlFiles`? Nothing prevents that

Comment: Sorry I may have been unclear @KlausGütter: I am actually looking for a way (if possible and in good design taste) to have one instance list variable which may contain either the `WriteOnlySqlFile` or the `ReadOnlySqlFile`, or a class with both read/write ops, and not have to cast at all - perhaps it was a silly thought to have.

Comment: What's wrong with casting? If it makes you feel better, you can use `LstSqlFiles.Where(x => x is ReadOnlySqlFile).Cast<ReadOnlySqlFile>()`. Alternatively, just keep a separate list for each of the types you want to keep separate from the others.